# Is the sentence 오늘(은) 제 생일입니다 right?

Tags: meaning

Is the sentence 오늘(은) 제 생일입니다 right? And if it is, what is the meaning of 제 in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

"오늘은 제 생일입니다." or "오늘 제 생일입니다." are both valid.
"제" is "my" in polite form (lowering yourself).

Also valid are "오늘은 내 생일입니다." (less polite)

Comment: Well, considering several conditions where 합쇼체 is used, I disagree that "오늘은 내 생일입니다" is valid. I am not denying that some people actually use it but pointing out the inconsistency in the use of honorifics. I would not recommend such mixing. "오늘 제 생일이에요" is a safer and better one.

Comment: @Klmo you have a point. I guess it is used rarely in that way.

Comment: “오늘은 내 생일입니다” reminds me of an old man’s talking. Or a title of a book. Half-honorifics. Haha.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more perfect if you use “오늘은 제 생일날입니다”. Here it’s added “생일+날” because it’s more emphasis on the day that the speaker want to mention. Plus, through my experience living in Korea, I many time heard Korean people say “생일날” when they want to mention the day.

Back to your question “제”. It means “my”. “제” is the polite word and advanced word in Korean language and culture. Remember that, if speaker speaks to stranger or person in higher position than him/her or the one who is older than him/her, using “제” makes the speaker look polite and knowledgeable in Korean language.

In addition. “제” is shorten from “저의”. You can use both of them exchangeably.

Comment: “_생일날?_” I have never heard “생일날입니다” before; every time I heard that, it was always “생일입니다.” We’re probably from different generations, then. And besides that, both “일(日)” and “날” mean a “day,” so “생일날” is basically a “birthday-day.” Yes, it’s a thing; and so does “역전앞.” I believe those tautological words are best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be used in Korea.
But many Koreans use “오늘은 제 생일입니다.” much more than “오늘 제 생일입니다.”.
“제” mean “my”
오늘은 제생일입니다. = Today is my birthday.